# Strange WPF errors in Visual Studio

Tags: wpf

Does anybody know of the reason why ""could not create instance of UserControl"" error can occur. It seems to me that it occurs completely spontanous, for example after I add space after node or change tabulation. Maybe it's some kind of VS bug?

Here are controls. This configuration actually raises an error

```
<UserControl x:Class="ShortcutsPrototype.KeyboardShortcutsTreePanel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ShortcutsPrototype="clr-namespace:ShortcutsPrototype">


    <Grid Margin="3,3,3,3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <ShortcutsPrototype:KeyboardShortcutsTreeView />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="3,3,3,3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">Reset</Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>


<UserControl x:Class="ShortcutsPrototype.KeyboardShortcutsTreeView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ShortcutsPrototype="clr-namespace:ShortcutsPrototype"
    Height="300" Width="300">

    <Grid>
        <TreeView>
            <TreeViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <ShortcutsPrototype:KeyboardShortcutsTreeViewEntry x:Name="generalTreeViewEntry" Title="General" />
                </TreeViewItem.Header>

                <TreeViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <ShortcutsPrototype:KeyboardShortcutsTreeViewEntry x:Name="generalNewFileTreeViewEntry" Title="New File" ShortcutKey="Ctrl+N"  />
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                </TreeViewItem>

                <TreeViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <ShortcutsPrototype:KeyboardShortcutsTreeViewEntry x:Name="generalOpenFileTreeViewEntry" Title="Open File" ShortcutKey="Ctrl+O"  />
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                </TreeViewItem>

                <TreeViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <ShortcutsPrototype:KeyboardShortcutsTreeViewEntry x:Name="generalSaveFileTreeViewEntry" Title="Save File" ShortcutKey="Ctrl+S"  />
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                </TreeViewItem>

                <TreeViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <ShortcutsPrototype:KeyboardShortcutsTreeViewEntry x:Name="generalSaveAsFileTreeViewEntry" Title="Save File As.." ShortcutKey="Ctrl+Shift+S"  />
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                </TreeViewItem>

            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <ShortcutsPrototype:KeyboardShortcutsTreeViewEntry x:Name="debugerTreeViewEntry" Title="Debuger" />
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <ShortcutsPrototype:KeyboardShortcutsTreeViewEntry x:Name="refactoringTreeViewEntry" Title="Refactoring" />
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>



<UserControl x:Class="ShortcutsPrototype.KeyboardShortcutsTreeViewEntry"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="25">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition  />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="titleLabel" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
        <Label x:Name="shortcutLabel" Grid.Column="1"></Label>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something in your CodeBehind file is throwing an exception. Have you checked that?

Comment: Hm, probably you are right. I was believed in ReSharper and threw away extension of UserControl class in code behind. After reading it it did work again without issues

Answer (score 0):

I have found that visual studio has quite the difficult time with WPF user controls.

The only thing that I can see is that it seems to use the latest compiled version of a control.  Usually, building the solution will fix the errors I have.  Sometimes, if I have multiple projects I have to build them manually one by one.